# Comic about bipedal reptiles, man who hears voice in head

Tags: story-identification, comics

I read this comic a few years back.

The civilization in it is similar to that of the Dark Ages but with bipedal reptiles who oppress mankind. The main character fights them with guidance of a woman he hears in his head. Later, it is found that the reptiles were actually aliens and the whole world they were on was actually a giant colony ship floating through space.